# How I handle x button modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need to handle a button when the user clicks "X" in modal. This is what I tried:

```
var modal = bootbox.dialog({

    message: dataTopicRilievo,
    title: 'Selezionare data topic in rilievo',
    buttons: {
    success: {
    label: "Save",
    className: "btn-primary save",
    callback: function() {

        console.log("HIII");

    },
    close: function(event,ui) {
    console.log("CLOSEEEEEEEEEEEEE");    
    }
});
```

But this first version doesn't work so I used:

```
modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

    console.log("CLOSEEEEEEEEEEEEE");

});
```

This part of code is not correct because the method that calls the modal is also hidden from positive action. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What version of bootstrap you use? In v3 it's `$('selector').modal()` not `.dialog()`

Comment: If you want something more specific with the button you can use jQuery selector to find the node element in DOM and code your need.. you could try to use something like $('modal modal-body bootbox-close-button').click(function() { // your_code } ); .... the Bootstrap call is an abstraction from some "preseted" event handling

Answer (score 3):

Try binding event directly to close buttons:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.modal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click(function () {
    console.log('Closed modal');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        TEST
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```